# How do I ROLLBACK my Oracle PL/SQL debug session (SQL Developer)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I debug my PL/SQL program using the debugger in Oracle SQL Developer, why is the work being done permanent? I want the work to be ROLLBACK at the end.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior for an Oracle session when it finishes, in general, is do a COMMIT.

When wondering about committing changes in your session when running PL/SQL, you also want to make sure your PL/SQL program itself is not:

1. doing a COMMIT in the code
2. running any DDL, such as creating or altering an object - this causes an implicit COMMIT

Now, as for debugging a PL/SQL program.

Do debug some PLSQL, we EXECUTE it.

When you start your debug session, you'll see the anonymous block of PL/SQL we use to kick off your program.

Scroll to the bottom -

[image]

Take that last line

```
--rollback
```

And remove the --

Now when our debug session runs, the very last thing that will happen before ending the session is the ROLLBACK.

Now, let's DEMO a full scenario. Here's some simple PLSQL - take in an EMPLOYEE_ID and update the EMPLOYEES table taking that employee's FIRST_NAME and making it UPPERCASE.

```
create or replace procedure upper_EMP_NAME (
          EMP_ID_IN      in             number,
          EMP_NAME_OUT   out            varchar2
        ) as
         new_name varchar2(50);
        begin
          select upper(FIRST_NAME)
            into new_name
            from EMPLOYEES
           where EMPLOYEE_ID = EMP_ID_IN;

           update employees set first_name = new_name
           where EMPLOYEE_ID = EMP_ID_IN;

           emp_name_out := new_name;
        end upper_EMP_NAME;
```

Note: you may need to disable the TRIGGERs on this table for this to run.

Now let's do the DEBUG. We'll run this with EMPLOYEE_ID 101. We'll see what the local variable is set to, and the OUT parameter from running it. Then we'll see after it's done running, that EMPLOYEE 101 still has the original first name.

[Animated GIF demo](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/debug-rollback.gif) (sorry too big for SO)